# Is it a bad idea to send the hash of a password instead of the unhashed password?

Tags: javascript, hash, passwords, security

For example, if the user has JavaScript enabled, we send hash his password and send the hash. If not, we send the password unhashed and a flag to mark that it is unhashed. We then build the hash (if it's unhashed) and compare it to the stored hash.

This seems to be secure and simple. Why isn't it a popular way to send a password? Did I miss something?

In another word: why better is lose hash then unhashed password? (imo most of us have only few passwords to many sites)

Comment: Don't try to implement your own security scheme. You'll get it wrong in both subtle and not-so-subtle ways. Use tried-and-tested systems instead.

Comment: but i still don's see anything wrong with mine :)

Comment: @Rinz: neither do I, but that's not a sufficient requirement for it to be a good security scheme. Security bugs can be incredible subtle and anyone who's not an expert in this field should avoid producing their security scheme.

Comment: @Rinz - And that's the problem...

Comment: I do. If you send a password unencrypted, it can be sniffed. If someone knows how you mark a password as opposed to a hash, then they can set up a sniffer to look for things going to your site marked as an unhashed password and obtain them.

Comment: Can someone proficient in English please reword this?

Comment: Your solution does not change anything. Take the password "123" hased it would be f.e. "345". Now the hacker can sniff "345" and sends it to your server and your server will accept it. So where is the point of hashing it?

Comment: To put it simply, it's not a popular method because it's not secure method and you did miss several things!

Comment: And let's not forget the fact that it is being hashed is plain to see right in the javascript code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript can always be tampered with. By hashing the password using JavaScript you at least are exposing your rules on how to store passwords. From a hacker perspective it's the same thing to catch the real password and send it to you system or to catch de hashed password and send it to your system.

If you really need to improve password security I would recommend using https and hashing it at Server side. Don't forget to use a salt key.

Answer (score 9):

The real problems here are man-in-the-middle attacks, where someone sniffs what comes down the wire. It doesn't matter if you send the hash of the password or the password itself, if someone downstream can read this, they can log in as that person. The only secure option is to use SSL to stop anyone but the server from being able to decrypt the password-hash/password.

Comment: well SSL can be circumvented too. There is a man-in-the-middle to do that

Comment: With challenge/response you can deal with this issue.

Comment: mfeingold - Yes SSL can be circumvented by the proxy tricking the user to post their details under http:// rather than https://, but if a user is smart enough to ensure they are logging in on a page that has a valid certificate of the site they're on, the proxy cannot get their password. Obviously not all users would know to check this. It may not be 100% fool-proof, but it's as good as it gets.

Comment: SSL is secure. However, as JonoW explained, it can be circumvented by "automated" social engineering - but only by that. Then again, that's probably enough. :)

Comment: Ilari, there is recent news that makes "SSL is secure" require a caveat: http://www.cgisecurity.com/2009/11/steve-dispensa-and-marsh-ray-have-published-a-paper-describing-a-weakness-in-the-tls-negotiation-process-from-the-whitepaper.html

Answer (score 3):

Then I just wiretap the hash and log in with that?

If you're concerned about security you should be using SSL. Then you can just send the password as is.

Also, SSL proves that the server they're logging into is not someone impersonating you.

Comment: Agreed.  Certs are so cheap now, why lose sleep over it?

Answer (score 1):

Note, that if you only hash the password, the hash is going to be **exactly the same** each 
time.

You should rather use some kind of challenge/response mechanism similar to APOP in POP3 protocol

Comment: @Rinz: then send a challange together with the login form.

Comment: Challenge should change each time the user logs in (use thread id, timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

You're making your job more complex than it is. Just send the password as plain-text, a hash won't improve security in any way. (See other's answers)

If you use the same hashing algorithm for storing the passwords in your databases, you actually decrease security. Because if someone can get the hashed passwords from it, he can use them to authenticate himself. (He doesn't have to dehash them) If you have SQL injection or other information leaking problems on your website, this will be the case.

Answer (score 0):

See [Perl/Javascript MD5 Secure User Authentication](http://perl-md5-login.sourceforge.net/) for an implementation and discussion.

Answer (score -1):

My recommendation is to send the hash.  Although you are exposing your internal security mechanism it does a couple of things.  If someone obtains the hash, that person knows that you don't store passwords in your system and may act as a deterrent for trying to steal your credential repository.  Second, you are protecting the end users original password.  Even if someone gets the hash, they do not have the original password, which may allow them to circumvent other systems where the user has used the same or similar password (salting would prevent the hash from being used elsewhere).  Also, pre-hashing the password allows you to strictly set character limits and alphanumeric validation on the back end.